# PHP to Display MySQL results in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have a working PHP set of code and am trying to get this displayed on my site.
I just need it to display as a two column table with the first column being the machine and the second being the status. I don't mind displaying the machine column using just static html or pulling this info from the database. Appreciate the help.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $user = "root"; 
    $pass = "hello"; 
    $db = "GYM"; 
    $r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

    if (!$r) {
        echo "Could not connect to server\n";
        trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            echo "Connection established.\n";
        }

        $r2 = mysql_select_db($db);
        if (!$r2) {
            echo "Cannot select database\n";
            trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
            } else {
                echo "Database selected.\n";
            }

            $query = "SELECT status FROM use_instance ORDER BY instance_id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

            $rs = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$rs) {
            echo "Could not execute query: $query";
            trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
            } 

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                echo $row['status'] ;
            }
        mysql_close();
        ?>
```

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated. Try `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$pass = "hello"; 
$db = "GYM"; 
$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$r) {
    echo "Could not connect to server\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
            echo "Connection established.\n";
    }

    $r2 = mysql_select_db($db);
    if (!$r2) {
            echo "Cannot select database\n";
            trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
            } else {
                    echo "Database selected.\n";
            }

$query = "SELECT machine, status FROM use_instance ORDER BY instance_id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

            $rs = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$rs) {
            echo "Could not execute query: $query";
            trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
            } 

            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Machine</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>

            <?php

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                 ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['machine'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
                 </tr>
                 <?php
            }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) not mysql  as mysql is deprecated .

This code should work

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $user = "root"; 
    $pass = "hello"; 
    $db = "GYM"; 
    $r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

    if (!$r) {
        echo "Could not connect to server\n";
        trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            echo "Connection established.\n";
        }

        $r2 = mysql_select_db($db);
        if (!$r2) {
            echo "Cannot select database\n";
            trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
            } else {
                echo "Database selected.\n";
            }
            // add the machine name as a column to your query
            $query = "SELECT machine, status FROM use_instance ORDER BY instance_id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

            $rs = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$rs) {
            echo "Could not execute query: $query";
            trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
            } 
           //start the table tag
           echo '<table>';

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                //display each row in the table
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row['machine'].'</td><td>'.$row['status'].'</td></tr>' ;
            }
           //close the table tag
           echo '</table>';
        mysql_close();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a HTML tag in php code
 Simply you can write HTML tags in echo.

For example

```
echo"<table border = "1">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
    {
     echo " <tr><td>".$row['status']."</td></tr>";
     } 
   echo"</table >";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use mysqli_fetch_objects as well
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_object.asp